# yii2 pretty url not working on form submission

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, yii2

Here are the rules I am using for the Url Manager.

```
'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'enableStrictParsing' => false,
            'rules' => [
            'post/<arg1>/<arg2>/<arg3>/<arg4>' => 'post/filter',
            'posts' => 'post/index',
            ],
        ],
```

And my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
# If a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

The rule seems to be working and urls like

`post/filter?arg1=9&arg2=0&arg3=d&arg4=3` is getting turned into,

```
post/9/0/d/3
```

However, I have a search form like below

```
 $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'action' => Url::to(['post/filter']),
        'method' => 'get'
```

the fields in the form are named  `arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4`. Now whenevr I submit the form the url gets back to the format

```
post/filter?arg1=9&arg2=0&arg3=d&arg4=3
```

I am not sure if its got something to do with the rules or the way I am submitting the form (I need submit the form by GET method only). Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Yii2 URL manager rules and forms with GET method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30516476/yii2-url-manager-rules-and-forms-with-get-method)

Answer (score -1):

Try this rule

```
'post/filter?<arg1:\w+>=<val1:\d+>&<arg2:\w+>=<val2:\d+><arg3:\w+>=<val3:\d+><arg4:\w+>=<val4:\d+>' => 'post/filter/<val1>/<val2>/<val3>/<val4>'
```

Comment: its not working
'display/<val1>/<val2>/'=>'search/index?<cid:\d+>=<val1:\d+>&<s:\w+>=<val2:\w+>',
'search/index?<cid:\d+>=<val1:\d+>&<s:\w+>=<val2:\w+>' => 'display/<val1>/<val2>/'

both way not working